# R tidyverse - How can I create an age group from an excisting age group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT0rR.png)

I need to make a new age range with the existing one and combine 25-39 with 40-59.
To make it simple to understand;
one column named age_range <- c(18-24, 25-39,25-39,40-59,40-59,60+)

i need to make a new age range as new_age_range <- c(18-24, 25-59,60+)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522594/combine-factor-levels)

Comment: There are several options to recode a variable, using e.g. `ifelse` you could do `new_age_range <- ifelse(age_range %in% c("25-39", "40-59"), "25-59", age_range)`.

Comment: thanks @stefan, if_else worked out perfectly.

Comment: Great. Just a reminder for the future and to avoid your question from being downvoted. Try to provide a snippet of your data and the code you tried. For more see [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: indeed I provided my data's image by the link where it writes "enter image description here".  I didin' shared the codes I tried because they didin't worked out, and I didn't remember recoding and if_else! but anyways thanks for the solution and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (based in Tidyverse) is to use the fantastic *case_when()* function to specify a new column called new_age_range. The *case_when()* function tests to see whether age_range contains either "25-39" or "40-59" and if it does it recodes this as "25-59". If the age_range column does not contain these values then it simply returns their original value.

```
age_data <- tibble(age_range = c("18-24", "25-39", "40-59", "60+"))

age_data %>%
  mutate(new_age_range = case_when(age_range %in% c("25-39", "40-59") ~ "25-59",
                                   TRUE ~ age_range))
```

The *case_when()*  works by testing the expression to the left of the ~ sign. If the first expression is true, then it assigns the value to the right of the ~ sign. If it is false, then it evaluates the next expression, and so on. The benefit of this method is that when you have a lot of nested *ifelse()* statements, you can substitute them with a single *case_when()* function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ alphabetac. At first I used if_else as @stefan proposed till I found out that I had not one but 3 age ranges that I need to recode. It is where case_where came to the rescue! as in my case, case_when is the right recoding function